# Firebase User Doesn't Have Constructor?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Flutter/Dart and Firebase. I'm using provider to grab Firebase user info and I'm seeing this error:

```
The class 'User' doesn't have a default constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'User'.
```

The code causing the issue is:

```
providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
        StreamProvider<User>.value(
          initialData: User(
            name: 'Friend',
            uid: '0',
          ),
          value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          // initialData: ,
        ),
```

I don't have a user class. The User class is coming from Firebase so how could I possibly add a constructor to it? Is there a way to get around this constructor error in the `initialData` field?

There's a UserInfo class that has a constructor. But, when I try using that, I can't set any default values for the fields. I'm getting `The named parameter 'uid' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'uid'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I change the initialData value to the following, the errors disappear. Not sure why this works to be honest seems to me like it should cause some errors, but it's not so I'll roll with it for now.

```
StreamProvider<User>.value(
          initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
          value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          // initialData: ,
        ),
```

Comment: It seems to me that the reason this is working is that you _are_ returning a constructor of _User_  (FirebaseAuth.instance) along with the actual property itself, _currentUser_. These constructors and properties are already built in the _User_. Just like any other Widget in Flutter, they hold properties and widgets that can be accessed. We do exactly that when we create our own custom Widget/Class.

Comment: Flutter state confuses me so much. I always see provider errors in my debug window, but it works in the application.

Comment: I figured `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` would just be some kind of getter and not a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you cant create a user object, you need to receive it from Firebase.
in the initial data you tried to create an User object so you got an error.
honestly i tried to replicate your error but couldnt find from where did you find the named constructors.

some helpful lines of code:

you can get the current logged in user like this:

```
 User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

or like this if you sign in with email and password:

```
 final UserCredential signInResponse = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email,
password: password);

final User user =signInResponse.user;
```

if you want to create a new user one of the options is:

```
 final UserCredential createUserResponse = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email,
password: password);

final User user =createUserResponse.user;
```

hope this helps, if not tell me what did i miss and ill try to correct my answer :)

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using Google and Facebook for sign ins and then my StreamProvider was using the `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` to get the state of the users sign in. I don't use standard e-mail login. So before the Flutter null safety, I was able to use the code in my original post. I figured out an odd solution that works for some reason. I'll post it.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't allow you to add a default to User for initialData like I'd expect.